# Обновление сложной модели

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net

Здравствуйте! При обновлении сложной модели Object-Coordinates для Coordinates создается новая запись. Не подскажите, как обновить уже существующую запись для Coordinates или добавить новую в случае отсутствия таковой?

**Обновление**

```
public class Center1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// это PK для Center1
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...
}
public class Center2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// это PK для Center2
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...
}

//Center1 и Center2 - два совершенно разных класса, но у них у обоих есть координаты:
public class Coordinates
{

}

Coordinates {
  public virtual Center1 { get; set; }
  public virtual Center2 { get; set; }
}
//здесь задаются FK
```

Обновлял стандартно

```
var oldModel = this.Collection.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==model.Id);
            if (oldModel == null)
            {
                oldModel = model;
                _context.Entry(oldModel).State = EntityState.Added;
            }
            else
            {
                //Center
                _context.Entry(oldModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
oldModel = model;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: А что вы пробовали? Очевидное решение не подходит?

Comment: @simlex опишите подробнее, что за "сложная модель", что за Object-Coordinates и Coordinates, как вы пробовали обновлять, что именно не получилось и какие ошибки при этом были. Баян, но все же: телепаты в отпуске.

Comment: @simlex: Очевидное решение — это поискать существующую запись в коллекции записей, если найдена, обновить, а если не найдена, добавить.

---
Код, существенный для понимания проблемы, лучше добавить прямо в вопрос.